# Trying to install matplotlib on a macbook pro

Tags: python, macos, matplotlib

I need to use [matplotlib](http://matplotlib.org/) for a school project and cannot get it installed on my mac. I downloaded a version of it but when I try to import it does not work. I have mac os x 10.5.8 and was wondering if anyone could recommend where I could find the proper package.

Comment: It's a tricky one to install. I got it to work using [macports](http://www.macports.org/). (Using macports python as well.)

Comment: There are already tons of questions on installing matplotlib on OSX, and there are so many things that can go wrong with such an installation it can be hard to debug without knowing exactly what steps you took.  Y

Comment: I managed it via `pip` -- Same version of osx too.  What version of python? What is the error message?

Comment: python version 2.7.3 and something goes wrong with numpy module is what the error message displays

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could never get it to work the proper way so I did it through GitHub.

Open terminal and do:

```
git clone https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib.git
```

Then change to the folder it will make automatically (which is in your home folder) and do:

```
python setup.py build
```

then

```
python setup.py install
```

It's probable you'll have to sudo for some of those.